# Sitecore Next.js Sitecore Forms Validation

Tags: sitecore-forms, validation, nextjs

I faced several issues getting the validation running with `Sitecore Forms` in combination with `Next.js`.

- Issue 1: backend validation is not executed
- Issue 2: backend validation was not showing up as errors on the client side

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1: backend validation is not executed**

- Check if Validator is checked on form editor field properties and is saved on the item in a correct way.
- I had to set the attributes on my inherited ViewModel Value property like `[DynamicRequired]`, `[DynamicValidation]`

**Issue 2: backend validation was not showing up as errors on the client side**

- Check if your Sitecore validation item has a language version of your form and the message field filled up because otherwise, the client will not get an error message even if the validation failed.